# how do you delete specific contacts in ICS?

Tags: contacts, samsung-nexus-s

I have a Nexus S phone just updated to ICS. This forum was very helpful in finding out ICS' now more cumbersome way to delete specific calls from call logs. Thank You.

It's a new year, and I want to clean out some dead wood from the contact list. But for the life of me I cannot find a way on the phone to delete a specific record from the contacts list.

Is a browser into my gmail contacts screen my only option to manage deletion of individual names on my phone's contact list?

Is my only contact management option on the phone to clear the whole list and re-sync after updating the list on the web site?

Answer (score 3):

Open a contact from the "People" app (the contact list) by tapping on its name, then press the `Menu` button (the Galaxy Nexus analogue to this should be the `...` button). One of the menu options should be "Delete".

Comment: Yup, that's what I see. "Edit, Share, Delete, Set ringtone, All calls to voicemail".

Comment: Thanks much, this works as an alternative. I was trying to delete a specific contact from the phone app (I seem to remember that I could do that in the last OS) but now realize that I must go to the People app. Have already cleaned out the list.